# Xpath exclude child element

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying to use DOM Xpath to get the price of a certain product from a shopping website.

The code I am using:

```
$scriptRow = $scriptDOMXPath->query('//p[@class="ps-sell-price"]/*[not(span[@class="visuallyhidden price-text"])]');
```

But, I still get the span no matter what. How can I get rid of that?

Now I am getting Price: 9999 RON. I need to drop the "Price: "

The span.visuallyhidden is the class of the "Price: "

Edited to show example:

```
<p class="ps-sell-price"> 
<span class="visuallyhidden price-text">Price:</span> 
<span >199,99 RON</span> 
<meta itemprop="price" content="199.988068" /> 
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RON" /> 
</p>
```

Thank you,
Cristian

Comment: Without a sample of the html you're parsing, I'm not sure how we can help.

Comment: Just edited, thank you :)

Comment: I'm really thinking you're better off getting just the <meta> tags here? They look perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the following does the trick:

```
//p[@class="ps-sell-price"]/*[not(self::span[@class="visuallyhidden price-text"])]
```

I must read the docs carefully as I do not understand what self:: does in XPath.

Thank you,
Cristian

Comment: Seems like it set the context for the given query operator otherwise without it it would probably be looking at child elements